# Saving multiple passportjs providers into same user document in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I'm having a problem I'm not able to resolve. I'm developing an app with nodejs, using mongodb, expressjs and passportjs as my authentication middleware.

I currently have 3 strategies: facebook, twitter and instagram. What I want to achieve is that when a user login for the first time, if the user is logged with one strategy and logs in with another one save the profiles into the same mongodb user document.

This is my auth/index.js:

```
require('./local/passport').setup(User, config);
require('./facebook/passport').setup(User, config);
require('./twitter/passport').setup(User, config);
require('./instagram/passport').setup(User, config);

var router = express.Router();

router.use('/local', require('./local'));
router.use('/facebook', require('./facebook'));
router.use('/twitter', require('./twitter'));
router.use('/instagram', require('./instagram'));
```

And this is, for example, my auth/twitter/index.js

```
var router = express.Router();

router
  .get('/', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    failureRedirect: '/',
    session: false
  }))
  .get('/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    failureRedirect: '/',
    session: false
  }), auth.setTokenCookie);

  module.exports = router;
```

But how could I pass for example a mongodb _id to this auth/twitter/passport.js in order to pass it to the mongoose query and update an user? Something like making a POST to auth/twitter and accessing to req.user._id ? I can't figure out how to do it.

```
exports.setup = function (User, config) {
  var passport = require('passport');
  var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
  var TwitterApi = require('twitter');

  passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: config.twitter.callbackURL
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    User.findOne({
      'twitter.id_str': profile.id
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        user = new User({
          role: 'user',
[...]
```

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**
This is how I set my cookie:

```
function setTokenCookie(req, res) {
  if (!req.user) return res.json(404, { message: 'Something went wrong,       please try again.'});
  var token = signToken(req.user._id, req.user.role);
  res.cookie('token', JSON.stringify(token));
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

and the signToken function:

```
function signToken(id) {
  return jwt.sign({ _id: id }, config.secrets.session, {     expiresInMinutes: 60*24*30 });
}
```

Why req.user and req.session are always empty in my Strategy?

**EDIT2:**

I think I could use the auth.isAuthenticated() function to attach user to the request before invoking the Strategy. What I have done is this:

```
router
  .get('/', auth.isAuthenticated(), passport.authenticate('twitter',  auth.isAuthenticated, {
    failureRedirect: '/',
    session: false
  }))
  .get('/callback', auth.isAuthenticated(),  passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    failureRedirect: '/',
    session: false
  }), auth.setTokenCookie);
```

But now I'm having this problem:

```
UnauthorizedError: No Authorization header was found
```

My request to auth/twitter comes from a $window.location. It seems that this does not attach the user object to the request, because when I make a GET or POST using isAuthenticated() the user object is passed correctly. This is my isAuthenticated() function:

```
function isAuthenticated() {
  return compose()
    // Validate jwt
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
      // allow access_token to be passed through query parameter as well
      if(req.query && req.query.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
        req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.query.access_token;
      }
      validateJwt(req, res, next);
    })
    // Attach user to request
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
       User.findById(req.user._id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!user) return res.send(401);

        req.user = user;
        next();
      });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I just dealed with this decoding the JWT token in my Strategies. I don't know if this is a good practice but the problem was I was not having my user attached to the request if the request was made with a $window.location.href
So in my strategies I read the cookie and decode it on the fly for searching a user in database.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can set `passReqToCallback` to `true` when you define your passport strategy. It will make the current request, thus the current logged in user available to your callback function.

```
exports.setup = function (User, config) {
  var passport = require('passport');
  var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
  var TwitterApi = require('twitter');

  passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: config.twitter.callbackURL,
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    User.findOne({
      'twitter.id_str': profile.id
    }, function(err, user) {

      if (err) return done(err);

      if (!user) {

        if (req.user) {
[...]
```

Comment: I tried to do it, but req.user is always empty, as well as req.session. In my browser I can check that the cookie is correctly set...